# How to add two boxplots in a same graph in ggplot2

Tags: ggplot2, boxplot

I have this sample data.

```
sample <- data.frame(sample = 1:12, 
                     site = c('A','A','A','B','B','B','A','A','A','B','B','B'), 
                     month = c(rep('Feb', 6), rep('Aug', 6)), 
                     Ar = c(7,8,9,8,9,9,4,5,7,5,8,9))
```

And created two boxplots

```
ggplot(sample, aes(x=factor(month), y=Ar)) +
   geom_boxplot(aes(fill=site))

ggplot(sample, aes(x=factor(month), y=Ar)) +
   geom_boxplot()
```

I wonder if there is a way to combine them in the same graph so that total, site A and site B are right next to each other per each month.

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize `dplyr` (via the `tidyverse` package) and `reshape2`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

sample%>% 
  dplyr::select(-sample) %>% 
  mutate(global = 'Global') %>% 
  melt(., id.vars=c("month", "Ar")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(month, Ar)) + geom_boxplot(aes(month, Ar, fill=value))
```

This drops the sample column as you aren't currently using it, adds the term global in a separate column, reshapes the data via the `melt` function and generates a figure. Note that I changed the input code format in your original question. With the changes to the data.frame you no longer need to coerce the variables to factors.